# C# Syntax issue in my If statment

Tags: c#, mysql, if-statement

Im having issues with my if statment and would like some one to look in to it I think my main issue is in:

`(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text))`

I want if all the statements are false it should execute mysql command (Ps it is working for the moment but the syntax fells wrong.)

```
        if (appointment.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text))
            {
                txtFirstName.BackColor = Color.Red;
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter first name!");
            }
            else
            {
                txtFirstName.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text))
            {
                txtLastName.BackColor = Color.Red;
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter last name!");
            }
            else
            {
                txtLastName.BackColor = Color.White;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text))
            {
                txtEmail.BackColor = Color.Red;
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Email!");
            }
            else
            {
                txtEmail.BackColor = Color.White;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text))
            {
                txthotel.BackColor = Color.Red;
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid hotel!");
            }
            else
            {
                txthotel.BackColor = Color.White;    
            }



            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text)) 
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ///register client
                connect.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into client (firstName,lastName,Nationality,mobile,email,budget,comments) value(@firstName,@lastName,@Nationality,@mobile,@email,@budget,@comments)", connect);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtFirstName.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtLastName.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", txtNationality.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtMobile.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@budget", int.Parse(txtBudget.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", txtComments.Text);


                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();

                loadclient();



                ///register appointment
                connect.Open();
                command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into appointment(Hotel,Roomnumber,AppointmentDate,Appointmenttime,ConfirmBy,Propertytype,Bedrooms,Purpose,Interestedin,Departuredate) value(@Hotel,@Roomnumber,@AppointmentDate,@Appointmenttime,@ConfirmBy,@Propertytype,@Bedrooms,@Purpose,@Interestedin,@Departuredate)", connect);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hotel", txthotel.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roomnumber", int.Parse(txtRoomNumber.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppointmentDate", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Appointmenttime", cmbTimeApp.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmBy", cmbConfirm.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Propertytype", cmbpropertytype.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bedrooms", cmbBedRoom.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", cmbPurpose.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interestedin", cmbIntrestedIn.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departuredate", dateTimePicker3.Value.Date);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Appointment registered!");
            }



        }
```

Comment: I don't think there is any syntax problem... you could switch the `if` and the `else` statement. Then your condition would become `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) ...)`. So you wouldn't have to write any empty `{ }`.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously any logic expression of the type:

```
if  (Condition1 || Condition2 || Condition3 || ....) 
{
    DoA();   
}
else
{
    DoB();
}
```

can be transformed to:

```
if  (!Condition1 && !Condition2 && !Condition3 && ....) 
{
    DoB();   
}
else
{
    DoA();
}
```

This would solve your problem but code readability would still be suspect

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) &&
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) &&
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text) && 
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text))
{
    //...
}
```

Yuck!

How can we improve this? Sometimes simply using auxiliary local variables makes your code so much easier to read; it highlights the semantics of your code and hides the mechanics. Locals are extremely cheap (or even free), use them!

Consider the following approach:

```
var isValidFirstName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text)
var isValidLastName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text)
var isValidEmail = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text)
var isValidHotel = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text))
```

And now your `if` statement looks like this:

```
if (isValidFirstName &&
    isValidLastName &&
    isValidEmail && 
    isValidHotel)
{
    //...
}
```

Doesn't that read much better?

But why stop here? Can't we just abstract the whole guest info validation away? Sure we can:

```
public static bool IsValidGuestInfo(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string hotel)
{
     var isValidFirstName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text)
     var isValidLastName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text)
     var isValidEmail = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text)
     var isValidHotel = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text))

     return isValidFirstName && isValidLastName && isValidEmail && isValidHotel;
}
```

And now your `if` statement is simply:

```
 if (IsValidGuestInfo(firstName, lastName, email, hotel))
 {
     //...
 }
```

Now that reads even better, *semantics are clear* and the mechanisms used are not in the way. Also, to boot, if you need to validate guest info anywhere else in your code you will not need to duplicate code.

Comment: If you use params string[] you could have it take any number of strings, rather than limiting it to four.

Comment: @w69rdy True, I'm sticking to the OP's concrete case. The whole approach is obviously very improvable but you have to stop somewhere ;). I just wanted to get the main idea through, not elaborate on the optimal solution.

Comment: @InBetween, I am inclined to upvote your answer but I tend to concur what w69rdy said. It could have been perfect that way.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it all into the `if` and drop the `else` part

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text)) 
{
    //register client
    connect.Open();
    ...
```

Comment: While I agree with the idea, it is better to negate the whole condition than to negate each of the operands.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this

```
(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text))
```

is true if any of the operands are true. You are putting this into an empty if and the else handles the command. This is correct, but it is overcomplicated. You can check it like this

```
        if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text))) 
        {
            ///register client
            connect.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into client (firstName,lastName,Nationality,mobile,email,budget,comments) value(@firstName,@lastName,@Nationality,@mobile,@email,@budget,@comments)", connect);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtFirstName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtLastName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", txtNationality.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtMobile.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@budget", int.Parse(txtBudget.Text));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", txtComments.Text);


            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();

            loadclient();



            ///register appointment
            connect.Open();
            command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into appointment(Hotel,Roomnumber,AppointmentDate,Appointmenttime,ConfirmBy,Propertytype,Bedrooms,Purpose,Interestedin,Departuredate) value(@Hotel,@Roomnumber,@AppointmentDate,@Appointmenttime,@ConfirmBy,@Propertytype,@Bedrooms,@Purpose,@Interestedin,@Departuredate)", connect);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hotel", txthotel.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roomnumber", int.Parse(txtRoomNumber.Text));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppointmentDate", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Appointmenttime", cmbTimeApp.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmBy", cmbConfirm.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Propertytype", cmbpropertytype.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bedrooms", cmbBedRoom.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", cmbPurpose.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interestedin", cmbIntrestedIn.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departuredate", dateTimePicker3.Value.Date);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Appointment registered!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Lajos' answer is beautiful one.
I might want to try it the other way around:

```
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txthotel.Text)) 
{
   return; //Isn't it short and simple?
   //Or if you want to jump somewhere and not to exit....
   goto dosomething:
}

    dosomething:
    MessageBox.Show("Something is blank! ");
```